# Shell within php or send variable from php to shell

Tags: php, shell

I'm working on a PHP script in which I have to run shell script,

I have 2 option:

1. If I'm able to send php variable value to shell
2. Or I can write shell directly in PHP

I used

```
shell_exec(dirname(__FILE__) ."/shl.sh");
```

for execute shell .... Now the problem is .. if i use #!/usr/bin/php in shell it only resolve code within `<?php ?>` and print shell statement directly on screen.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you run a PHP shell script from PHP instead of using it's code directly in your (web) PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

The best option (by far!) would be to modify the external script to accept command line parameters.

So instead of

```
shell_exec('sh.sh');
```

where all variables are embedded, make it into

```
shell_exec("./sh.sh $opt1 $opt2");
```

where you can pass your variables easily.

An example for a bash script to use these arguments would be :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "My $1 will kick your $2 anytime"
```

which will replace $1 with the first argument, and $2 with the second.

Comment: I had used it but it didnt execute my shell script , if i run shl.sh directly it executed

Comment: when i try to execute it by php , it gave www-data as output

Comment: @vs7: other than the path of the file (added `./` in the example), this works for me just fine in a small example I put on a server. Check your error logs - are you allowed to execute shell scripts from PHP?